# Typescript variable saying undefined in ionic taxi booking app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a taxi booking app that has fetches riders from a firestore database and displays it to the homepage.

Here is get rider function that fetches riders from database in my rider.ts file

```
Rider.ts

public rider: Observable<Rider>;

getDriverRidesUser(id){
    this.RiderCollection.doc<any>(id).valueChanges()
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.rider = data;
        console.log(this.rider);
    });
}
```

`console.log` gives me an object of a single rider.

in my home.ts file, I try to get `this.rider` and save it to another variable and i get `undefined`.

```
home.ts


public driverId: number;

public requestedRider;

constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform,
    public geo: Geolocation, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public riderProvider: RiderProvider
){
    this.requestedRider = this.riderProvider.rider;
    console.log(this.riderProvider.rider); //saying undefined
    this.driver.getDriverRides(this.driverId);           
}
```

Why is it giving me `undefined` in my home.ts and giving me the correct object in my rider.ts file?

Comment: You have to subscribe to the rider variable and then call to the getDriverRidesUser function so your observable will get resolved and then you'll have the data

Comment: @Osakr kinda new to Observables and all can you show me by giving an answer?

Comment: Well so, think that inside your getDriverRidesUser function you're subscribing to an observable, which is returned by the valueChanges() method. So you only need to subscribe to your variable ( `this.riderProvider.rider.subscribe( res => this.data = res )` ) and then call to the getDriverRidesUser in order to give data to your rider variable and resolving the observable sending the data to the subscribers

Comment: add a nullguard like this `console.log(this.provider && this.provider.rider ? this.riderProvider.rider: 'elsishfoobar'); //saying undefined`